# Any way to handle an exception thrown from called c# exe in c++?

Tags: c++, exception

I wonder any way to handle inner exceptions of I called exe from c++ code?

My sample code:

```
char *fProg = "..\\ConsoleApp\\EZF\\EncryptZipFtp.exe";
char *fPath = "C:\\Users\\min\\Desktop\\Foto";
char *fPass = "wxRfsdMKH1994wxRMK";

char command[500];
sprintf (command, "%s %s %s", fProg, fPath, fPass); 

try 
{
   system(command);
}
catch(exception &err)
{
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't a way to handle an exception thrown under a different framework. However, if the program returned an error code, you could exploit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the return value from `system()` (as you need to check the return value from all C functions).  Like this:

```
int status = system(command);
if (status == -1)
    std::cerr << "oops, could not launch " << command << std::endl;

int rc = WEXITSTATUS(status);
if (rc != 0)
    std::cerr << "error from " << command << ": " << rc << std::endl;
```

If the child program is at all well-behaved, it will return nonzero to indicate failure when an unhandled exception occurs.